# How to map an array of objects in another object from JSON in Java

Tags: java, json, spring, mapping, resttemplate

I need to call an API using `RestTemplate` to get a JSON which should be automatically converted into Java objects.

A sample JSON looks like this

```
{
    "ParsedResults": [
        {
            "TextOverlay": {
                "Lines": [],
                "HasOverlay": false,
                "Message": "Text overlay is not provided as it is not requested"
            },
            "TextOrientation": "0",
            "FileParseExitCode": 1,
            "ParsedText": "Translated message",
            "ErrorMessage": "",
            "ErrorDetails": ""
        }
    ],
    "OCRExitCode": 1,
    "IsErroredOnProcessing": false,
    "ProcessingTimeInMilliseconds": "1296",
    "SearchablePDFURL": "Searchable PDF not generated as it was not requested."
}
```

I've also created a class to map all the data when I call my desired API (getters and setters not included for clarity).

```
public class OCRResponse {

    @JsonProperty("ParsedResults")
    private List<ParsedResults> parsedResults;

    @JsonProperty("OCRExitCode")
    private String OCRExitCode;

    @JsonProperty("IsErroredOnProcessing")
    private boolean isErroredOnProcessing;

    @JsonProperty("ProcessingTimeInMilliseconds")
    private Long processingTimeInMilliseconds;

    @JsonProperty("SearchablePDFURL")
    private String searchablePDFURL;
}
```

The class above includes a collection of objects consisting of following fields and it should represent an array shown in JSON.

```
public class ParsedResults {

    @JsonProperty("TextOverlay")
    private TextOverlay textOverlay;

    @JsonProperty("TextOrientation")
    private String textOrientation;

    @JsonProperty("FileParseExitCode")
    private String fileParseExitCode;

    @JsonProperty("ParsedText")
    private String parsedText;

    @JsonProperty("ErrorMessage")
    private String errorMessage;

    @JsonProperty("ErrorDetails")
    private String errorDetails;
}
```

This file has one more class made by me to map another part of my JSON, but I don't know if it matters so I won't paste it unless someone needs it.

Now, the problem is that if I start my application and make a call, the `OCRResponse` object has all the data it should except for `ParsedResults` object(s).

```
OCRResponse response = restTemplate.getForEntity(uriBuilder.toUriString(), OCRResponse.class).getBody();
System.out.println(response.getSearchablePDFURL());             //null (correct)
System.out.println(response.isErroredOnProcessing());           //true (correct)
System.out.println(response.getProcessingTimeInMilliseconds()); //406  (correct)
System.out.println(response.getOCRExitCode());                  //99   (correct)
System.out.println(response.getParsedResults());                //null (invalid result)
```

I've tried to change `List<ParsedResults> parsedResults` to

```
ArrayList<ParsedResults> parsedResults;
ArrayList<ParsedResults> parsedResults = new ArrayList<>();
ParsedResults[] parsedResults;
ParsedResults parsedResults //As I should get only one element in my collection anyway
```

but none of these worked and I constantly get `NullPointerException` or `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

I pretty sure it is possible to achieve my goal using this method, because I did something similar during my studies if I remember correctly.
Can someone help me figure out what's wrong here?

Comment: *FYI:* According to sample JSON, `OCRExitCode` should be `int`, `processingTimeInMilliseconds` should be `String`, and `FileParseExitCode` should be `int`. --- Although the name of the field is `ParsedResults` (plural), the type should be `List<ParsedResult>` (singular), since the `List` makes it plural. Same as `List<Car> cars` makes sense, i.e. it is a list of individual cars.

Comment: Thanks for the tips :). I didn't catch the fact that ```ParsedResults``` is plural in JSON because it is a ```List```/```Array``` and I'll fix it.